# Android - Display Int onClick with Buttons increment , decremet [Error: Cannot resolve method ‘display(int)’ ]

Tags: java, android

Android - Display Int onClick with Buttons increment , decremet [Error: Cannot resolve method ‘display(int)’ ]
I am getting a error on Android Studio as what I believe is because I'm inserting multiple 'displays'. Can someone advise & explain what I need to do and why it causes this error so I know for future?

Please see below for the following error:

```
package com.example.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView num = findViewById(R.id.num);
        Button order1 = findViewById(R.id.order);
        /**
         * This method is called when the plus button is clicked.
         */
        public void increment (View view) {
            int quantity = 2;
            display(quantity);
        }
        /**
         * This method is called when the minus button is clicked.
         */
        public void onClick (View view) {
            int quantity = 2;
            display(quantity);
        }


        /**
         * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
         */
        order1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int quantity = 2;
                display1(quantity);
                displayPrice(quantity*5);
            }

            /**
             * This method displays the given price on the screen.
             */
            private void displayPrice(int number) {
                TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price_text_view);
                priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
            }
            /**
             * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
             */
            private void display1(int number)
            {
                //  TextView quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                num.setText("" + number);
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we don't have anything called Local Function as a result, move the functions from the onCreate method to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, implement your methods onClick() and increment() outside of the function onCreate(). It does not make sense to implement a function inside of a fuction. You can implement them inside the class MainActivity. Moreover, I would suggest not to name your custom button click function as onClick() as it might lead to confusion later on.

Secondly, I cannot see the implementation of the function "display()". That's why AndroidStudio cannot recognize the function. If you move onClick() and increment() to the place I said and in the same class implement the display function, it should be fine.